# Not able to use predefined with bind function

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-bootstrap-datetimerangepicker library with bind() to get the selected dates from the calendar but 'onApply' function of this library passes 2 params (event, picker) and in 'predefined' I am not getting startDate and endDate that suppose be coming in second param. And without bind its not working

```
<DatetimeRangePicker
    timePicker
    showDropdowns
    timePicker24Hour
    onApply={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'predefined')} />


handleChange(event, picker) {
        this.props.sendDateRanges(payload);
    }
```

https://github.com/luqin/react-bootstrap-datetimerangepicker

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind `this` to your handleChange function for it to have lexical scope. Otherwise, `handleChange` has no notion of your component's `this` since it's block scoped. The second/subsequent arguments to bind are unnecessary in your case. What you're doing above is simply prepending the string 'predefined' to the `arguments` array. Instead, simply pass the bound function to the onApply prop instead.

`onApply={this.handleChange.bind(this)}`

If you're using es6 classes to define your component, a common pattern is to pre-bind all your event handlers and functions in the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
}
handleChange(event, picker) {
   //code
}
render() {
    return <div onChange={this.handleChange} />
}
```

If you want to get even fancier, you can use arrow function syntax which binds lexical scope implicitly. No need to call bind anywhere.

```
handleChange = (event, picker) => {
    //code
}
render() {
    return <div onChange={this.handleChange} />
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @kngroo. This worked but by using handleChange() function on click of apply button, I am trying to call redux to reflect date change in selector but till reducer I am getting new selected date but not in selector and therefore not updated getting nextprops in componentWillReceiveProps() . Can you tell what am I missing?

Comment: It's difficult to debug your issue without looking at your code. If you want to store and update the value of the date picker in redux, you need to dispatch an action from the handleChange function by calling redux's dispatch method with the `picker` data. Assuming your redux setup is done correctly, you need to ensure that your component is "connected" to redux. `connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46636800/react-selector-is-not-been-called here the question I posted, I did call the redux